# css margin-top-bottom not working iphone safari browser

Tags: html, css, iphone, responsive-design, media-queries

#### On iPhone Safari browsers, the elements inside the "home-sci" class appear distorted, whereas they look fine on the Chrome Toolbar. When I deploy the project to live view, I encounter issues on iPhone devices. How can I resolve this problem and ensure consistent display across different browsers and devices?

#### iPhone 13 [ScreenShoot](https://www.hizliresim.com/ir5ygl7). [Website](https://www.mertaraz.dev/)

HTML:

```
<section class="home" id="home">
        <div class="home-content">
            <h1>Hey! I'm <span>Mert Araz</span></h1>
            <div class="text-animate">
                <h3>Frontend Developer</h3>
            </div>
            <p>Tutkulu, yaratıcı ve kullanıcı odaklı çözümler sunmak için buradayım. 
                Web projelerinde estetik tasarımlar ve sürükleyici kullanıcı deneyimleri oluşturmayı hedefliyorum. 
                İşinizi dijital dünyada öne çıkarmak için size özgün ve etkileyici web çözümleri sunabilirim.</p>
                   
            <div class="btn-box">
                <a href="https://www.dostpen.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/Mert_Araz_CV.pdf" target="_blank" class="btn">CV İndir <i class='bx bx-down-arrow-alt'></i></a>
                <a href="https://github.com/measses?tab=repositories" target="_blank" class="btn">Projelerim  <i class='bx bx-briefcase'></i></a>
            </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="home-sci">
            <a href="mailto:mertaraz7@gmail.com" target="_blank"><i class='bx bxl-gmail'></i></a>
            <a href="https://github.com/measses" target="_blank"><i class='bx bxl-github'></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/muhammedmertaraz/" target="_blank"><i class='bx bxl-linkedin'></i></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/measssess" target="_blank"><i class='bx bxl-twitter'></i></a>
        </div>  
        <div class="home-imgHover">
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
.home-sci a:hover{
    color: var(--bg-color);
}

.home-sci a::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background:var(--main-color);
    z-index: -1;
    transition: .5s;

}

media query:
/*home contact*/
  @media screen and(max-width: 430px){
    .home-sci a{
        margin-top:20px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see property will support or not in all browsers using this website [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/)